# How to retrieve download Url using getDownloadUrl() after uploading to AngularFireStorage

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, ionic5

I have already successfully uploaded images into my firebase storage, but I also want to retrieve the downloadURL and add it into my firestore database. Console logging "url" returns me the link I want. But I am having trouble using it.

I have tried `this.profileImage = url` but console will always return me error Cannot set property 'profileImage' of undefined.
I have it defined by doing `profileImage` above the constructor.

I have also tried placing the entire firestore function inside but console will return cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined
I am using Ionic 5.

```
imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url)=> {
    this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.user.id).update({image.url})
       console.log("this is my image" + url)
})
```

this is what I currently have

```
uploadImage(imageURI) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      const imageRef = storageRef.child('image').child(this.createFileName());
      this.encodeImageUri(imageURI, function (image64) {
        imageRef.putString(image64, 'data_url')
          .then(function (snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot)
            resolve(snapshot.downloadURL)
            imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url)=> {
              this.profileImage = url
              console.log(this.profileImage)
              console.log("this is my image" + url)
            })
          }, err => {
            reject(err);
          })
      })
    })
  }
```

```
encodeImageUri(imageUri, callback) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      var aux: any = this;
      c.width = aux.width;
      c.height = aux.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      callback(dataURL);
    };
    img.src = imageUri;
  };
```

Comment: Check your profileImage see if it’s a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first snippet looks pretty close, but you aren't saving the actual `url` that you get from `getDownloadUrl()`. If you do that and combine it into your `putString()` callback, you get something like this:

```
imageRef.putString(image64, 'data_url')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url)=> {
        this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.user.id).update({ "imageUrl": url })
    })
  })
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but console will return cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined

Comment: OK. I updated the answer to use fat arrow notation for all callbacks, which should fix that.